# What does Notepad do differently under the hood than the PRINT command?

Tags: c#, .net, printing

I need to send content to printer in C# .NET the same way as `PRINT` command does.

I have Godex thermal printer with [QLabel](http://www.godexintl.com/product_content.aspx?id=9&cid=4) software bundled. Now it has the option to save the label as a command that you can pass to printer with command prompt `PRINT` command. The file looks like this:

```
^Q80,3
^W100
^H10
^P1
^S3
^AD
^C1
^R2
~Q+0
^O0
^D0
^E35
~R200
^L
Dy2-me-dd
Th:m:s
AH,0,0,1,1,0,0,X
AH,744,0,1,1,0,0,X
AH,746,560,1,1,0,0,X
AH,0,550,1,1,0,0,X
AG,160,208,1,1,0,0,
AA,234,283,1,1,0,0,Haloo
E
```

That works when i do something like this:

```
net use LPT2 \\localhost\godexUsbPrinter /yes
print /D:LPT2 label.cmd
```

And it prints my label out nicely.

Now, if i open this in notepad and print, it just prints me this text.

I wonder what does `PRINT` command do under the hood and how can i program my C# based program to replicate the behaviour? Because when i implement printing logic, it just prints me the plain text as notepad does.

I know i could call a `PRINT` command with Process.Start from C#, but i need to replace some placeholder value in the label template all the time. I could create a temporary file on the disk and print that, but i would prefer to avoid such a scenario.

Comment: i guess it translates ^Q and such into the corresponding control characters

Comment: print doesn't do anything under the hood in that regard, that is the difference. notepad tries its best to display whatever characters you have in the file but probably removes some non-printable characters in the process.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To be honest, the question title is the wrong way around. `PRINT` doesn't do anything spectalular at all, it just flushes all its input to the printer. It's Notepad that, through Windows' print system, sends various commands for paging and line endings and whatnot and eventually the data you want to print. The code you show is raw printer data, so you'll have to send it 'raw' and not as text. So technically it's a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123154/sending-raw-data-to-fedex-label-printer).

How to do so is explained [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/322091/en-us). It's using P/Invokes to `winspool.Drv`.

Comment: Thank you for clarification. This works. I should probably change the question title?